# To check if there are capital in a array c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a c++ function to find if the array has capital, but somehow it kept returning true.
Here is my function:

```
bool hasNoCapitals (const string array[], int n)
{
    bool result = true;

    for (int i = 0; i<0; i++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < array[i].size(); k++)
        {
            char word = array[i][k];
            if (word == tolower(word))
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else{
                result = false;
                k = array[i].size();
                return result;

            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    string arr[] = {"sa","DDDD","DDDDDDDDD","ffdd","sa"};
    cout << hasNoCapitals(arr, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use the standard library for this: https://godbolt.org/z/bY54sPEoY

Comment: @paddy Almost the same code! https://godbolt.org/z/rr7xfx3n4 I'd also use `std::vector`.

Comment: @rturrado almost, except mine also works on strings containing non-alphabetic characters such as spaces, digits and punctuation. ;)

Comment: @paddy aha! Now I understand the use of `none_of` for the inner loop. I was thinking if it had to do with `toupper` being more efficient than `tolower`. Great!

Answer (score 4):

The function always returns `true` because of a typo: you have `for (int i = 0; i<0; i++)`, which should be `for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)` instead.

So your loop is always empty.